# List items don't appear in Ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

This is my code:

```
$("#showing").append("<ul id='vrijemeObjava'");
for(i=0;i<App.vrijemeObjavljivanja.length;i++) {
    $("#showing").append("<li><strong>" + App.vrijemeObjavljivanja[i] + "</strong></li>");
}
$("#showing").append("</ul>");
```

This is made inside a FB.api call. The "App.vrijemeObjavljivanja is an array of dates which I want to put in an ul. The array is put in `<li></li>` but not in `<ul>`.

The end result looks like this.

```
<ul id='vrijemeObjava'></ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
```

Can someone please tell me why are the list items coming after the `</ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append, you append entire elements (both the opening and closing tags). Try this instead:

```
$ul = $("<ul id='vrijemeObjava'></ul>");

for(i=0;i<App.vrijemeObjavljivanja.length;i++) {
    $ul.append("<li><strong>" + App.vrijemeObjavljivanja[i] + "</strong></li>");
}

$("#showing").append($ul);
```

Comment: Your first line should be `$("<ul id='vrijemeObjava'></ul>")`

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure.  I usually like to be as explicit as possible, it (usually) prevents bugs :)

Comment: I agree, I usually do what you suggested as well.

Comment: This is the better answer because you only do one append to the DOM, with the full ul.

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
$("#showing").append("<ul id='vrijemeObjava'></ul>");
for(i=0;i<App.vrijemeObjavljivanja.length;i++) {
    $("#vrijemeObjava").append("<li><strong>" + App.vrijemeObjavljivanja[i] + "</strong></li>");
}
```

(in your exemple your ul open tag is not correctly built `.append("<ul id='vrijemeObjava'");` missing a **>** )

better version, storing the ul in a variable :

```
$ul = $('<ul/>', {id : 'vrijemeObjava'}).appendTo("#showing");
for(i=0;i<App.vrijemeObjavljivanja.length;i++) {
    $ul.append("<li><strong>" + App.vrijemeObjavljivanja[i] + "</strong></li>");
}
```

Comment: It's better to cache the the ul and append the li's, then append the final ul to #showing. It's faster.

Comment: Nop didn't work :/     I've tried adding another <div> element but when the browser hits the first line it erases the <div> element :S

Comment: @user2755330 where this div comes from ?
btw: i've added another possibility